# Homepage disappeared from Google results

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

Even that my traffic through Google raised approximately 40%, the homepage (`/`) of my page is gone from Google results even though I have no broken links.

How can I investigate the cause?

Comment: Have you looked at Google web master tools

Comment: Yes I have, and there's not any new indicator...

Comment: Are you sure it's been removed or you just cant see it ranking? Do a site colon search in Google like this to confirm if it has been deindexed:  site:example.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google can decide to remove your page from its index if:

- your page has duplicate content with an other page (internal or not)
- your page is not considered good enough to be indexed (thin content for example)
- your page is not accessible anymore for a long time (returns 404 HTTP status)
- your page is blocked by a *robots.txt*
- your page is blocked by an *.htaccess* file (returns 410 HTTP status for example)
- your site is penalized or blacklisted (because of spamming, bad backlinks etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Google removes homepage from page results if:

- Google thinks the site is down
- The homepage size is very small
- In a few cases I've noticed Google removing homepages with no link on the page

Answer (score 1):

Google may remove a site (including its homepage) from the search results if the site gets a penalty for being spamming.  Log into [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), verify your site, and check if there are any messages from Google about penalties applied to your site.